# How to start a bounty as a reward for a question that's protected?

Tags: support, bounty

I ran into a tricky issue on OS X where a windows was being displayed on a second monitor that was not present. I found a question and an answer at [Move an off-screen window back on-screen on Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/q/55341).

I'd like to reward @Hai Vu for his answer, but the bounty button is not available to me.

The Bounty system is kind of broken (or at least its not well suited for rewarding good answers), and I have not had any luck in getting things changed. Confer, [Provide a means to reward users and their answers (decoupled from bounties)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239088).

How do I start a bounty to reward @Hai Vu for his answer?

Or, can a mod transfer 25 points from my account and provide them to @Hai Vu?

Mods: we could also use a [bounty](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bounty) for this request, but the tag does not exist.

Comment: There's a 50 point minimum bounty. And eh, I wasn't aware that protecting a post removed the ability to bounty stuff. I can't give a *definitive* answer but I'll see what I can get done.

Comment: strange that I can see a [tag:bounty] tag on Meta (32+1 questions) as well as a start a bounty link on the question page. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @jww: I can also see the **start a bounty** button (and it brings up the normal screen when clicked) so it's not related to whether you are a moderator or not. Have you tried another browser in case something strange is going on with the one you are using?

Comment: I also have the ability to start a bounty on the question you linked too.